# Detect which URL from onclick to load appropriate content via AJAX /Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've looked all over and can only seem to find more static versions (for a lack of a better word) of what URL can be called through in an AJAX / Jquery request:

Jquery:

```
 $(document.body).ready(function () {
     $("li.span3 a").click(function (e) {
       $('.content').load(this.href);
       e.preventDefault();
          });
        });
```

HTML/PHP:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo 
    '<li class="span3 mobile_width"><a href="http://localhost/sites/wp-osprey/?team=jo-bloggs2">';

        the_content();
        the_title();
        echo '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
```

I'm wanting it to be a variable so it could listen out for which div was clicked and then display the corresponding external html as the onclick divs are in a while loop.

Would I need to create and add listen event on the onclick so it would grab the correct external URL or is there a different way to write the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly correct. To get the URL from the a href, you'll have to use, $(this).attr('href') instead. This is already binding the onclick event onto all your "li.span3 a" elements.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to get the value of the `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag that is clicked.

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {
    $("li.span3 a").click(function (e) {
        var thisURL = $(this).attr("href");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```